# Rotation - Math.PI divided by 32

Tags: android, layout, rotation

I have a layout that the user can swipe. While doing this, I want my layout to rotate, and I've been looking a way to achieve this. I found many examples where they include this line of code:

```
if (x_cord >= screenCenter)
                    cov.setRotation((float) ((x_cord - screenCenter) * (Math.PI / 32)));
```

For instance: [ImageView rotation API <17 acting wierd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328398/imageview-rotation-api-17-acting-wierd) http://software.techassistbox.com/imageview-rotation-api_442356.html

But I do not understand why Math.PI * 32. Does someone know this? I tried to google that but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a measure of radians.  An angle can be measured in degrees or radians.  A full circle is 360 degrees, or 2*pi radians.  So pi/32 is 1/64th of a circle, or a bit over 11 degrees.  Almost all mathematical functions use radians instead of degrees because it makes more mathematical sense.

So that function is rotating the object based on the distance from the screen center, in multiples of 1/64th of a circle.

Comment: everything is correct,  except one thing: setRotation accepts good old degrees...

Comment: THen I would bet that code was written by someone else who didn't know that.  I'm also shocked-  I've never seen a graphical function call that used degrees, its a horribly broken idea.  Math doesn't work in degrees, it works in radians.

Comment: Canvas.rotate,  Matrix.postRotate,  Matrix.preRotate,  Matrix.setRotate they all use degrees,  to be honest i don't know why